# Facebook Like Box API: Unable to alter height

Tags: css, facebook, api, facebook-likebox

I am using the facebook Like Box API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). I set the height in the supplied code generation boxes but it always reverts to the standard height. I try editing the code directly eg:

`<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/me" data-width="870"
 data-height="1000" 
data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>`

But this also does nothing to change it.

I have tried both the iframe and HTML5 versions of this to no avail.

I have also tried adding some inline CSS eg: `style="height: 1000px;"`. Also no luck there.

Width, for whatever reason, seems fine.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> height - the height of the plugin in pixels. The default height varies
>   based on number of faces to display, and whether the stream is
>   displayed. With the stream displayed, and 10 faces the default height
>   is 556px. With no faces, and no stream the default height is 63px.

From [your link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

Comment: I understand that, but surely there is a way to later the height when the stream is displayed so that there is less need to scroll?

Comment: I think not. Facebook creates an iframe inside that div. You can change the size of the iframe, but can not change the elements within it

Answer (score 0):

The height of the element inside the IFRAME was changing as per the height value you put in the Facebook code until a few days ago. Something seems to have changed at Facebook. I have two sites that are effected. Both were displaying the like box at the height I declared until very recently.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me as well after working for the past 12+ Months.  I tried recreating the code using several different options and it seams to be a code bug within the Facebook Application itself.  Wondering if anyone there knows of the issue and if we can expect it to be fixed soon.  My site: http://peachtreebennett.com/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can no longer change the height. As some have stated, in the past, changing the data-height in their provided code would change the height of the iframe as well as the content inside it. This no longer happens.

Even the generator on Facebook's dev site has a height input field, but changing it does nothing. Try it for yourself here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/